# Problem with getting response of a HTTP Web request

Tags: c#, response, webrequest

You can see my code down there.This is going to show user id of a instagram user as the response but it is showing "�".

```
private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = ""; // your username
        string password = ""; // your password 
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-IG-Connection-Type", "WiFi");
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-IG-Capabilities", "AQ==");
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Instagram 10.9.0 Android (23/6.0.1; 944dpi; 915x1824; samsung; SM-T185; gts210velte; qcom; en_GB)";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en;q=1, ru;q=0.9, ar;q=0.8");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", "mid=qzejldb8ph9eipis9e6nrd1n457b;csrftoken=a7nd2ov9nbxgqy473aonahi58y21i8ee");
        httpWebRequest.Host = "i.instagram.com";
        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        byte[] bytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("ig_sig_key_version=5&signed_body=5128c31533802ff7962073bb1ebfa9972cfe3fd9c5e3bd71fe68be1d02aa92c8.%7B%22username%22%3A%22"+ username + "%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22"+ password  +"%22%2C%22_uuid%22%3A%22D26E6E86-BDB7-41BE-8688-1D60DE60DAF6%22%2C%22_uid%22%3A%22%22%2C%22device_id%22%3A%22android-a4d01b84202d6018%22%2C%22_csrftoken%22%3A%22a7nd2ov9nbxgqy473aonahi58y21i8ee%22%2C%22login_attempt_count%22%3A%220%22%7D");
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)bytes.Length;
        using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        string result = new StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = result;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to share your `bytes` here?

Comment: @Icepickle i know there is my username and password there but that's an useless account...

Comment: You send `"Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"` so `httpWebRequest.GetResponse()` is going to return a zipped or deflate stream, not a string.

Comment: @Dour High Arch yeah you solved my problem.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's answered in a comment by @Dour, but I'm going to add a bit of detail that isn't mentioned.

This following line tells the server: Hey server! Please send me a compressed response (to reduce size).

```cs
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

so, the response you're getting is a compressed response.

Does that mean you just remove this line ?

Well, Removing it will fix your problem but that isn't the correct way to do that.

It's really better to get a reduced size response because that will need lower time to download it from the server.

What you really need to do is to make `HttpWebRequest` handles the decompression process for you.

You can do that by setting `AutomaticDecompression` property.

```cs
httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
```

**Note:** With the previous line, you do NOT need to set `Accept-Encoding` yourself. `HttpWebRequest` will send it automatically for you. And when you call `GetResponse`, `HttpWebRequest` will handle the decompression process for you.

---

Besides of your problem:
I suggest that you use `using` statement for getting the response, because with your current code, I think it won't get disposed.